# Windows 10 bluetooth pairing problems

Tags: windows-10

I have a problem with my JBL Charge 3, I connect to my laptop but in Sound Control Pannel it appears disconnected and no sound is playing on them.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: How did you paired it / how are you trying to use it?

Comment: normal. I just put my jbl in pair mode and my pc found it and connected to it but no music plays

Comment: OK, after pairing can you select the Bluetooth audio device?

Comment: No. Like I said in Sound Control Pannel the JBL is still shown as disconnected.